# JAXB does not serialize the full object graph

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, marshalling

I have left out all other properties etc from the classes. None of the lists that I have in Question is serialized. I have added an example of the Answer list. The JSON reponse is fine except that "answers" is null. Why? The quiz object is fully initalized (yes, taken care of even though it is lazy loaded, custom code in repository layer) when I print it to console. I also used debugger to check.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Quiz {

    private List<Question> questions;

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
}

public class Question {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QuestionId", nullable = false)
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "answers")
    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(final List<Answer> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Answer")
public class Answer  {

}
```

---

EDIT:

Seems like the uncommented code is causing trouble. Switching the commenting makes the code working.

```
public void setAnswers(final List<Answer> answers) {

        //this.answers = answers;

        this.answers.clear();

        for (Answer answer : answers) {
            addAnswer(answer);
        }

    }

public void addAnswer(final Answer answer) {
    if (!(answers.contains(answer))) {
        checkThatOnlyOneAnswerMayBeCorrect(answer);
        answers.add(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the logic in the setter causing trouble?

Comment: Are you sure the `answers` field is ultimately populated?

Comment: Yes. And it works when I just use this.answers = answers;

Comment: I suspect there is an error in your set logic.  If you post enough code to reproduce the issue I can look at it.

Comment: The strange thing is that it commenting in/out what I have below makes all the difference. The same apply on the other lists.

Comment: I found out why, it is all the Hibernate/JPA crap. It fails. I am rewriting the code to use JDBC instead. All good.

Comment: Instead of rewriting your application because Hibernate does something wrong you could just switch JPA implementations.  I'm part of the EclipseLink team.  We offer both JPA and JAXB implementations and put great emphasis on making sure they work together.

Answer (score 2):

An important thing to note about [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations is that if you have pre-initialized a `List` value that value will be used.  For example if you your `answers` field is initialized as follow that instance of `ArrayList` will be used.

```
List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
```

And if you initialize your `answers` field as follows that instance of `LinkedList` will be used.

```
List<Answer> answers = new LinkedList<Answer>();
```

That means the problem is with the following code.  When you perform `clear` on the `answers` field you are also clearing the value being passed in since they are the same instance.

```
public void setAnswers(final List<Answer> answers) {

    //this.answers = answers;

    this.answers.clear();

    for (Answer answer : answers) {
        addAnswer(answer);
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-choosing-list-implementation.html

Comment: @Andy - I have updated my answer, I think I've finally figured it out.